How can I dynamically access a non-static variable from a static context in Java?
I am trying to write a program that converts a character input into uppercase. However, I am facing a “non-static variable cannot be referenced from a static context” error. I understand this error usually means that static methods cannot access non-static fields, but I am not sure how to refactor my code without breaking the current functionality.
Here is my code:
package javaapplication3044;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class JavaApplication3044 {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); // Scanner declared here

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("Enter a character: ");
        char inputChar = scanner.next().charAt(0); // Error occurs here
        upperLetter(inputChar);
    }

    public static void upperLetter(char c) {
        if (Character.isLetter(c)) {
            char ch = Character.toUpperCase(c);
            System.out.println("The uppercase version of " + c + " is " + ch);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Error: not a letter");
        }
    }
}

What I tried:
I read about static vs. non-static methods and variables, but I’m struggling to find the best way to refactor this code. Should I make scanner static, or is there a better design approach?
Expected Outcome:
I want to understand the best way to allow access to a non-static variable (scanner) from a static method without breaking my program’s structure

There’s not much structure to break — why is the scanner static?

@DaveNewton I assume you meant not static

Can you not just declare scanner as follows: static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);, i.e. make it a static member variable rather than an instance variable.

@MarkRotteveel It’s been a day

Hello Retaj, the problem arises from what, in my modest opinion, is a conceptual error, we are in “Java”, which is “POO”, we must work with objects, the ideal solution is to create an object JavaApplication3044 in the main method, and from it, invoke a method of the class, like this: new JavaApplication3044().init();... I only create static methods, if I need static methods.

The error occurs because the scanner object is not static, but it is being accessed from a static context. To fix this, you can declare the scanner object inside the main method. Here is the corrected code:
package javaapplication3044;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class JavaApplication3044 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); // Scanner declared here
        System.out.print("Enter a character: ");
        char inputChar = scanner.next().charAt(0);
        upperLetter(inputChar);
    }

    public static void upperLetter(char c) {
        if (Character.isLetter(c)) {
            char ch = Character.toUpperCase(c);
            System.out.println("The uppercase version of " + c + " is " + ch);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Error: not a letter");
        }
    }
}

